# How to set user account Name/Surname in postfix?

Tags: linux, postfix, users, accounts

I created a user account in postfix in the form: editor@example.org.

When I receive emails from that account, in gmail, for example, the senders name is "editor", but I want to show something like "Editor Surname".

Any idea of how to it? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree that the best way is to configure your account details in your own mail client.

However, if this is a local unix account you're talking about you can use `chfn(1)` to change the real name of a user with something like:

```
chfn -f "Editor Surname" editor
```

or by editing directly the `/etc/passwd` file (both require superuser access).

Answer (score 3):

You should set it in the mail-client in your account configuration.